# Search Console unable to access website after DNS change

Tags: google-search-console, dns

I recently switched hosting providers from Bluehost to Siteground and transferred and repointed my domain to Siteground. After this transfer, Google Search Console no longer works for me. When I enter my URL in the URL inspection tool, I get an error "URL not in property. Inspect a URL in the currently selected property or switch properties". I then try to add an additional verification method, the HTML file method. I put the file in the root of my folder in my new host and I was successfully verified. However, I still get the error "URL not in property" when I attempt the URL inspection tool again. I also see no data was recorded since Friday (today is Sunday), so it has been more than 48 hours since I repointed the DNS from bluehost's servers to siteground's servers.

What can I do to get my console working again and ensure googlebot is crawling my site properly?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to remove the property and then re add the property. Google Console prompts you to verify via DNS when you re-add. This helpful siteground article helped me out: https://my.siteground.com/support/kb/site-tools-vs-cpanel-comparison-create-aaaa-srv-txt-records

Edit: Upon coming back the next morning, when I ran some of my urls through the URL inspector and click "View Tested Page", I see Google still crawls the old site. I know this because I added some structured data with Yoast SEO plugin to the page I was testing (the page on the old host did not have structured data). The "ld+json" tag which contains this data was on my website but not on the HTML out put by the tested page.

I contacted SiteGround and they added the default robots.txt file for me. I also flushed the Google Cache with Flush Cache. I used my domain name and the RR type set to TXT (because that was what I used as per the siteground tutorial linked above to verify via DNS). In order to do this, had to create a DNS record in my SiteGround account.

After couple of hours of the robot.txt being added and the google cache being flushed, the the URL inspection tool, Live Test > View Tested Page now shows the correct page.

Comment: Verify by DNS record isn't the only means of authenticating ownership of the site in Search Console.

Comment: No it is not. But I had previous authenticated with tags prior to the migration and I didn't know if there was a way to re-verify. I then tried to verify with the HTML page. This was successful, but google still gave me the 'URL not in property' issue. It was only when I verified with DNS that google said it had no records of the property. Which I guess is kind of expected? And when I checked it again today, Google is still testing URLs from my old site although the DNS verification is with the new hosting provider. Probably needs some time...

Comment: Having just had to set up a new property in Search Console (something I've not done for a while), there is a strong benefit to using the DNS verification method, in that it covers the domain and _all_ subdomains, which is a far simpler process if you use subdomains.